# Python Feedparser is missing an entry called "name" in the parsed output

Tags: python, xml, feedparser

I have an XML file `filename.xml` with the contents

```
<product>
  <sku>144249</sku>
  <productId>119223</productId>
  <name>Cannon Digital Camera</name>
  <imageurl>http://bla.com/blu.jpg</imageurl>
</product>
```

and I am using the Python [Universal Feed Parser module](http://packages.python.org/feedparser/introduction.html) to parse it like this:

```
f = feedparser.parse('filename.xml')
```

The resulting parsed output (below) is missing the `name` entry yet everything else is there.

```
{'bozo': 0,
 'encoding': 'utf-8',
 'entries': [{'imageurl': u'http://bla.com/blu.jpg',
 'productid': u'119223',
 'sku': u'144249'}],
 'feed': {},
 'namespaces': {},
 'version': ''}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the file you are trying to parse a feed? If not, why don't you try a more general purpose XML parser such as the one found in `ElementTree` or `lxml` instead?

Comment: Yes, the file is a the feed I pasted above. Dint know about lxml, trying it now.

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is another useful option for parsing a non-feed XML file.

Comment: What you posted isn't an RSS feed, or at least not a complete one. Is there more to the file than what you are showing?

Comment: I guess I dint know the difference between a feed and an XML file then. I thought they are the same. btw I am able to parse without any problem using the lxml library that @GiulioPiancastelli suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use another tool for the job - this is not an [RSS feed](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html). The easiest reason to point out is all RSS feeds must have an `<rss>` root node, this does not.

XML is a generic format for storing data, RSS is a format based on XML designed for syndication of content. They have different purposes.